# Did Allah leave no vicegerants for jinnkind?

Tags: jinn, shia-sunni, shia-imam, imamah

Twelver believe there has been continously a vicegerant on earth from times of adam.

They say 12 imams are for mankind. What about jinnkind?

I have asked twlevers on discord regarding the same and no answer is given by them.

So the question is who's vicegerant for jinns?

The necessity for jinns requiring vicegerant as per twelver logic is from Quran verse 51:56.

> We didn't not create jinn and men except to worship me.

I also have come to conclusion that the population of jinn is more than mankind at any given time based on hadith which says every human  has a devil companion.

> His companion (qareen) will say: ‘Our Lord! I did not push him to transgression, (in disbelief, oppression, and evil deeds), but he was himself in error far astray.’
> Allaah will say: ‘Dispute not in front of Me, I had already in advance sent you the threat.
> The Sentence that comes from Me cannot be changed, and I am not unjust  to the slaves’”
> [Qaaf 50:27-29]

> The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “There is no one among you but a companion from among the jinn has been assigned to him.” They said, “Even you, O Messenger of Allaah?’ He said, “Even me, but Allaah helped me with him and he became Muslim (or: and I am safe from him), so he only enjoins me to do that which is good.” 
> According to another report, “… There is assigned to him a companion from among the jinn and a companion from among the angels.” 
> Narrated by Muslim, 2814

Answer (score 1):

According to the Shiites, prophets and the 12 Imams are also the prophets and Imams of the jinn.
That is, they must obey human leaders

Comment: Twelver are forbidden to communicate with jinn.also you need to provide evidence

Comment: Twelfth Interpretation - Volume 12 - Page 92 / noor assagholain v5 p19-20/ https://mesbahyazdi.ir/node/6462/%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B3-%DA%86%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF%D9%87%D9%85-%D8%AC%D9%80%D9%80%D9%86

Comment: s.maodtaba.b nothings help there still no answers

Answer (score 0):

In the Qur'an, the principle of the existence of jinn has been confirmed and some features have been mentioned in the explanation of jinns.
For goblins, two time periods are assumed. A time period before the creation of man and a time period after the creation of man. In the second period; That is, after the creation of man, which is common between jinn and humans (both before the advent of Islam and after the advent of Islam), according to what is stated in the verses of the Qur'an, jinns, like humans, were obliged to be prophets sent among humans. They were human beings to follow. Accordingly, many goblins believed in the divine prophets and another group did not believe and became infidels.

But in time; Before the creation of man, when God had not yet created man, but created the jinn, it can be said: Before the creation of Adam (AS), there were prophets of the genus among them; Because:
On the other hand, the Holy Qur'an considers the purpose of creating jinn and humans as worship and evolution and says: "Indeed, I created jinns and humans for worship."
And on the other hand, it is clear that it is not possible for God, the Wise, to oblige the jinn, but has not taught them their duties, components and conditions, and has not sent them as guides. Therefore, the duty of jinn and humans is a branch of sending a prophet, and it is not permissible until a prophet is sent.

But no information is available about the information and names of the prophets of the jinn. And this is while human beings are still engaged in controversy and denial and non-acceptance regarding the acceptance of visible human prophets. What is the advantage of knowing more about what is not visible and validable by us ?!

https://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/fa851

https://www.qudsonline.ir/news/478309/%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%A7-%D8%AD%D8%B6%D8%B1%D8%AA-%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF-%D8%B5-%D9%BE%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A8%D8%B1-%D8%AC%D9%86-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D9%87%D9%85-%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%AF